# Is there a program which allow easily to add speech bubbles to a video/screen cast?

Tags: video-editor, screencast

I am currently creating a screencast tutorial for a lecture. Therefore, I use recordmydesktop to get a video of my actions. Now I want to annotate some actions in the video with speech bubbles (or something similar) because the videos should be without sound.

Is there a good Linux/OpenSource video editor which provides such a feature?

Comment: I think openshot had such a feature, but not completely sure?!

Comment: OpenShot is only able to insert simple titles. But theres is not possibility to create speech bubbles or similar ones.

Comment: I think you won't find a solution for such need. What I can suggest is the usage of pre-made transparency speech bubbles, text balloons, etc. in order to place them over your video, then improve them with the text overlay provided in the majority of the video editors. I personally prefer the usage of kdenlive, which is more like a Sony Vegas Pro/Adobe Premiere alternative. Good luck!

Comment: `lodraw` can do it: Shape | Insert | Callout. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7336/67438